# Displaying HTTP video stream in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, html5-video

I'm a beginner in Angular and everything related.

I have an IP camera which streams video with a certain address (the real IP omitted in the example):

```
http://admin:password@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Streaming/channels/102/httppreview
```

When I paste the address in the browser, the video shows up with no problems; the same with VLC player.
I looked at the source code in the browser, which is simply:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
  <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;"
    src="http://admin:password@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Streaming/channels/102/httppreview">
</body>
</html>
```

When I pasted the above source code into a file and saved it as an .html file, all I saw was a broken image icon... How come?

What do I need to use to simply display an HTTP stream? I've looked into Videogular and HLS.js but nothing seemed to work...

In the end what I need to do is to place the link into an already built Angular project which displays multiple cameras.

Angular camera source code:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { IMapCamera } from '../../Models/map-camera';
import { HttpService } from '../Http/http.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CamerasService {
  public readonly _camerasMapping = new BehaviorSubject<IMapCamera[]>(null);
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  getCameras() {
    return [
      {
        id: 1,
        iframeSrc:
          "https://www.youtube.com/embed/niyLE7ZhOqE?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&controls=0",
        station: "S1"
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

The YouTube link in the above code shows up perfectly, but when I try to replace the YouTube link with the IP camera stream address, nothing shows up... I can't figure out what is the problem.

Does anyone know what is the issue? Do I need to make changes in other parts of the Angular project?